# Is it possible to import all packages from a file like we do with requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am always typing a lot of:

```
import pandas as pd
import stuff from stuff
import etc...
```

Is there any way to make a list of imports in a file to use with one line code?

Thanks

Comment: You could make a a python script, say 'my_module.py' with all those imports and then go `from my_module import *`

Comment: IDEs will often have options to automatically add imports for things you might need, you may consider trying that route.

Comment: There's simply no reason to do this. You're avoiding something so incredibly common by introducing something unnecessarily complicated. I suggest you instead focus your efforts writing good code that follows accepted standards (e.g. PEP8).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I wouldn't call `from my_module import *` terribly complicated.

Comment: @martineau No, but unless it's being used by a lot of other scripts/modules, it's just unnecessary obfuscation and provides no value.

Answer (score 0):

Python follows the rule "explicit is better than implicit".
So it's intended to have all imports used at the beginning of your file, even there are many.

If there is too much, it can be a sign that you should split your file into multiple files belonging to the same package.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `list` of packages you want to import, saved as `my_list.txt`, you can do something like this:

```
with open('my_list.txt', 'r') as packages:
     for line in lines:
            __import__(line)
```

As a result, you will import every package indicated by `my_list`'s lines.